# Rails 4, scope on related model loads all enties (scope doesn't filter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, eager-loading

I have models like that:

```
class Post < AvtiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true).order(created_at: :desc) }
  scope :where_author, -> (author) { where("author LIKE ?", "#{author}%") }
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When on rails console I try:

```
 Article.find(123).posts.where_author("guest")
```

I get expected values.

But when I do this in  ArticlesController:

```
@articles = Article.includes(:posts).posts.where_author("guest") # I will use params array when it work
```

This loads all posts and ignores scope conditions, actually SQL query doesn't include scope part at all.

I've tried this with `joins` and `includes` with same result.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, you need articles but the condition is on the post

```
Article.joins(:posts).where('posts.author like ?', 'guest%')
```

There's a better way to do this using the scope that's only accessible from the `Post` model.

```
Article.joins(:posts).merge(Post.where_author('guest'))
```

Comment: But to use chaining like 
`Article.find(123).posts.where_author("guest").active` 
I will still have to use scopes and lambdas?

Comment: if `active` is an article scope then use it after you close the `merge( )`

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution (code I use in my project) is:

on Article

```
scope :post_author, -> (author) { joins(:posts).merge(Post.where_author(author)) }
```

on Post

```
scope :where_author, -> (author) { where("posts.author LIKE ?", "#{author}%") }
```

Now I can use scopes and chain them as follow:

```
@articles = Article.post_author(params[:post_author])
```

`merge()` part is very important here.

Thanks.